# Tableview First row not aligned

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, xml-parsing

I'm working on `xmlparser` and displaying the data from `[this xml]` to a mytableview. As you can see the first line is not aligned with the other rows.

This is how the rows are populated:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    cell.textLabel.text = [((AlbumObject *)[listFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]) title];

    return cell;
}
```

Am I missing something obvious?

[image]

**SOLVED** As you suggested the problem was some whitespace i couldn't see from the xml.This solved:

```
[currentStringValue appendString:[string
                             stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet
                                                              whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```

Comment: Is it possible that there's a variable number of spaces in front of the entries?  try printing the titles out in the NSLog as you display the cells, to see if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you suggested the problem was some whitespace i couldn't see from the xml.This solved:

```
[currentStringValue appendString:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
```